# android.content.ActivityNotFoundException crash report from Play Console

Tags: android

Stacktrace:

```
android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: 
  at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult (Instrumentation.java:1878)
  at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity (Instrumentation.java:1545)
  at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult (Activity.java:4283)
  at androidx.activity.ComponentActivity.startActivityForResult (ComponentActivity.java)
  at androidx.core.app.ActivityCompat.startActivityForResult (ActivityCompat.java)
  at androidx.activity.ComponentActivity$2.onLaunch (ComponentActivity.java)
  at androidx.activity.result.ActivityResultRegistry$2.launch (ActivityResultRegistry.java)
  at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment$9.launch (Fragment.java)
  at androidx.activity.result.ActivityResultLauncher.launch (ActivityResultLauncher.java)
  at cyberdynesoftware.jahresurlaubapp.YearFragment.lambda$showSchoolVacationDialog$5 (YearFragment.java)
  at cyberdynesoftware.jahresurlaubapp.YearFragment.lambda$showSchoolVacationDialog$5$YearFragment (YearFragment.java)
  at cyberdynesoftware.jahresurlaubapp.-$$Lambda$YearFragment$FLinyacBVg2yJZUeB9ggaBhktlA.onClick (lambda)
  at com.android.internal.app.AlertController$ButtonHandler.handleMessage (AlertController.java:173)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:102)
  at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:158)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:7224)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Native Method)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (ZygoteInit.java:1230)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:1120)
```

Unfortunately I couldn't reproduce the error locally. The stacktrace stems from Play Console; it happend on a Samsung Galaxy S5. This is the relevant part of the code in YearFragment:

```
private void showSchoolVacationDialog() {
    new AlertDialog.Builder(requireContext())
            .setTitle(R.string.schoolVacation)
            .setMessage(R.string.schoolVacationDialogMessage)
            .setPositiveButton(R.string.choose, (dialog, which) -> {
                activityResult.launch("text/calendar");
                dialog.dismiss();
            })
            .setNegativeButton(R.string.clear, (dialog, which) -> {
                db.schoolVacationDao().deleteAll();
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                dialog.dismiss();
            })
            .create()
            .show();
}

private final ActivityResultLauncher<String> activityResult = registerForActivityResult(
        new ActivityResultContracts.GetContent(),
        result -> {
            if (result != null)
                try {
                    InputStream inputStream = requireContext().getContentResolver().openInputStream(result);
                    if (inputStream != null) {
                        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(inputStream).useDelimiter("\\A");
                        addSchoolVacationToDB(iCalParser.parse(scanner.next()));
                        scanner.close();
                        inputStream.close();
                    }
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
        });
```

Why does this happen? Is there anything fishy with my code?

Comment: Are you sure that device has an Intent that handles  text/calendar?  This includes are you sure if it does have one that the user hasn't deleted or disabled that app?

Comment: I don't know anything about the users device. Is it risky to expect that? What I expect to happen is a dialog where the user can select an iCal file. This works in my testing.

Comment: It's always risky to assume that a certain piece/kind of software is installed on a user's device.  Which is what you're doing with the intent here.  For this case though catching the Exception and showing an error dialog would probably be sufficient.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As per the [documentation on `launch()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/activity/result/ActivityResultLauncher#launch(I)):

> This method throws [`ActivityNotFoundException`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ActivityNotFoundException.html) if there was no Activity found to run the given Intent.

While any of the `ActivityResultContracts` (such as the `GetContent` one you're using) *should* be available on every device, users may be running a custom build of Android that removes the apps / system utilities that handle these common intents or the user may have manually disabled the app (this is more common with things like a Browser or Camera app than this particular case).

Therefore you should consider surrounding your call to `launch()` with a `try`/`catch` block that catches an `ActivityNotFoundException` and informs the user that their device does not support this functionality.

Comment: Do the parameters to launch() matter? Would I get the same Exception if I were to call launch("*/*") instead? Would it make sense to do this in case of an Exception as a fallback?

Comment: In this particular case, no, any parameter would suffer the same problem.